# When I try to apply a certain git stash in VS2019, I get an error saying there are uncommitted changes (there aren't) and only one file is applied

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

> Git operation failed because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before retrying. See the Output window for details.

However there are no uncommitted changes. One file that was added is restored from the stash, but that's it - the rest of them are stuck in limbo.

How can I get the rest of my files from the stash? (Short of opening them one by one and copypastaing them into my project...)

Comment: What Output Window says?

Comment: Opening repositories:
C:\Users\edkol\source\repos\PlatformV2
Undoing edit: C:\Users\edkol\source\repos\PlatformV2\Src\Web\Web.config

Comment: I don't think the output window is displaying anything from this particular operation... That text I just pasted is from a previous operation where I undid a change to web.config

Comment: When you say there are no uncommitted changes, does `git status` actually report that your sandbox is clean? Can you edit your question and add the output of `git status`? (Run this command on the command line, please, not in VS2019.)

Comment: Oh well, I already opened all the modified files and copypastad the code into my project...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Running `git status` from my SourceTree terminal cleared up the error in Visual Studio.  Even though the output of the command didn't show anything of interest:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

...but after doing that, Visual Studio let me apply the stash.

Comment: Same story! This should be the right answer + Bug ticket to VS!

Comment: wild, i've run into this problem before and my solution was always to restart my PC.  This is much more time effective

Comment: 'git status' can also be run in the package manager console within VS 2019 if you don't have SourceTree.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was only solved after I have made a commit. I did a irrelevant change to a file and commited. After that my git stash apply worked fine. Hours struggling and just one commit solved the problem. I hope you have the same luck.

Comment: solved my problem. one thing to mention,  sometimes you have to checkout other branch to apply stash.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had added a file that was also added in the stash.  The files may have conflicted when applying the stash.